# вопрос по библиотеке aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

у меня есть инлайн кнопка с встроенной в нее юрл и мне надо отследить ее нажатие как это сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

Кнопка в библиотеке aiogram определяется следующим способом:
btn = aiogram.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=“Ваш текст”, callback_data=“ваша коллбэк дата, по которой вы будете далее работать”, url=“Ваша ссылка”)

Далее создаете декоратор по приему инлайн кнопок и рассматриваете введенную коллбэк данную в кнопке